# Using sed or awk how to change exchange/switch day and month in CSV file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a CSV file which contains the month/day/year in the last field. What I want to manipulate  the month/day field using sed or awk command.

This is my current CSV file looks like:

```
No non-compliant users,db2inst2,NA,C,13/09/2023
```

manipulate the day and month

The last field (date) should be formatted DD/MM/YYYY (09/13/2023)

```
No non-compliant users,db2inst2,NA,C,09/13/2023
```

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: can columns contain embedded newlines?

Comment: "13/09/2023" seems to be DD/MM/YYYY already.

Comment: Apart from the apparent error in the question (date now is month=13).. a source of valuable reading would be [AWK string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i am resolve my problem using the awk command.

**data:**
No non-compliant users,db2inst2,NA,C,13/09/2023

**AWK Script:**

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," } 
    { split($11, date, /\//)
      $11 = date[2] "/" date[1] "/" date[3]
      print $0 
    }
' inputfile
```

**Out come:**
No non-compliant users,db2inst2,NA,C,09/13/2023

Comment: maybe you can convince your users to adopt `YYYY-MM-DD` formatting, which is unambiguous and sorts naturally? Glad you solved your immediate problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `sed` solution, let `file.txt` content be

```
No non-compliant users,db2inst2,NA,C,13/09/2023
```

then

```
sed 's|,\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)$|,\2/\1/\3|' file.txt
```

gives output

```
No non-compliant users,db2inst2,NA,C,09/13/2023
```

Explanation: this is single substitution with 3 capturing group, I use `|` delimiters rather than `/` so I do not need to escape literal `/`, `$` denotes end-of-line, which prevent change in non-last field.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.8)*